# How to add two legends to bottom corners of plot (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with no x-label. Instead, I want to just have two text boxes on the bottom left (saying "Negative) and bottom right (saying "Positive").

I have my plot object (p), but have tried different ways to achieve what I want, failing each time. For instance, this does not create the text box in the bottom left of the plot.

```
p + legend.title("Negative") + legend.position(c("bottom","left"))
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the annotate function with which you can add text to a plot:

```
p + annotate("text", x = x-position-value, y = y-position-value, label = "Negative")
```

You can also add rectangles, lines and pointranges with this function. For some further details about how to use this function, [see the official documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/annotate.html)